# Mandelbrot's lacunarity realized by fractal or stochastic field?

Tags: stochastic-processes, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, image-processing, lacunary-series

It is my understanding that Mandelbrot came up with the notion of lacunarity to classify the homogeneity of 2D functions that only take two distinct values [see here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lacunarity)

I wonder, does there exist a stochastic model, such as a Bernoulli distributed random field or something like a spin system that in some scaling limit realizes a pre-specified lacunarity?

Or can you construct an explicit example of a fractal in 2D for any given lacunarity?

Comment: perhaps some helpful references are here "Relationship of second-order lacunarity, Hurst exponent, Brownian motion, and pattern organization", they get Lacunarity formulas for each fractional Brownian motion.